# SQL Search Result Error

Tags: php, sql, search

I was wondering if someone could please help

I have the below code to search a SQL database for results.

I am not getting some of the names coming up even when I type the persons full name in. If I place one letter of their name in it comes up?

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="keyword" name="keyword" value="" >

         <input class="btn-success btn" type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Submit" onclick="this.value='Sending, please wait...'">

        </form>

<<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST) ){
  $keyword = trim ($_REQUEST['keyword']);
echo "Keyword: ".$keyword;

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "user_name";
  $password = "*********";
  $dbname = "user_db";


  // Account Manager
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM work_staff WHERE staff_first LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR staff_surname LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     echo "Found: ".$row['staff_first']." ".$row['staff_surname'] ;
     echo " ";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<br>";
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
 ?>
```

Its really frustrating me. Any help someone can give would be great.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: can you provide one of that names which not coming up, and the keyword which you entered  ?

Comment: I have like Daniel Smith, Robert Smith, Robert Johns and Ash Jones in the database. I search for Robert and Robert Johns comes up but not Robert Smith. I also put in Daniel or Ash and nothing comes up. I place the letter A in and Daniel and Ash come up. Its really confusing

Comment: can you exec same query manually directly in mysql (in `phpmyadmin` or `mysql console`) : `SELECT * FROM work_staff WHERE staff_first LIKE '%Robert%' OR staff_surname LIKE '%Robert%'` and see if you get all users with Robert name

Comment: Hi, yes, when I place the statement into the myPHP SQL query it comes up with the results I am after perfectly

Comment: Ok then try to do following, add `var_dump($sql)` after `$sql = "SELECT * ..` and search for `Robert` and write here what printed

Comment: Nope, still only the one Robert. And, when I type in Dan nothing still comes up.

Comment: I mean not check the result but just add after `$sql = "SELECT * FROM work_staff WHERE staff_first LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR staff_surname LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";` add `var_dump($sql)` to see what exact query you have build

Comment: I did add the var_dump($sql) and tested it and the same result

Comment: after adding `var_dump($sql)` is sql query printed in your browser ? if yes what is look like can you posit it in comments ?

Comment: I found it. I had a Double << where the <?php was. it was <<?php. It screwed everything up. Working now

Comment: You can't find full name by this query as it not exists in db in  a single column for that you have to save `staff_first & staff_surname` in a single column may be `staff_name`;

Comment: Thanks I will take that into consideration.